# Can't infer type in TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
interface Command {}

class RemoveCommand implements Command {}

class AddCommand implements Command {}

type Params = RemoveCommand | AddCommand; 

type Result<T> = 
  T extends RemoveCommand ? { status: string, a: number } :
  T extends AddCommand ? { status: string, b: number }:
  { status: string }

function send<T extends Command>(command: T): Result<T> {
  if (command instanceof RemoveCommand) {
    return { status: '', a: 0 } as Result<T>
  } else if (command instanceof AddCommand) {
    return {
      status: '',
      b: 0,
    } as Result<T>
  }

  return {
    status: '',
  } as Result<T>
}
const r1: { b: number } = send(new RemoveCommand());
```

Show error:

> Property 'b' is missing in type '{ status: string; a: number; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.(2741)
> What I did wrong?

Comment: In `T extends RemoveCommand ? { status: string, a: number } :` shouldn't that be `b`  not `a` ?

Comment: Yes. Each command could use its own response

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues.

The first is that you've mixed up `a` and `b`:

```js
type Result<T> = 
    T extends RemoveCommand ? { status: string, a: number } :
    T extends AddCommand ? { status: string, b: number }:
    { status: string };
```

Says that `send(new RemoveCommand())` will return a member that *has `a`* not be, so your last line is incorrect.  When you fix that, you'll still get an error however.

The root issue is that `RemoveCommand` and `AddCommand` are the same (they're both empty classes).  You can see that by trying `let foo: RemoveCommand = new AddCommand()`, TypeScript will accept that too.

Once you define (differing) members on `RemoveCommand` and `AddCommand` your code will work.  For example:

```js
interface Command {}

class RemoveCommand implements Command {
  thingToRemove: string;

  constructor(thing: string) {
    this.thingToRemove = thing;
  }
}

class AddCommand implements Command {
  thingToAdd: string;

  constructor(thing: string) {
    this.thingToAdd = thing;
  }
}

type Params = RemoveCommand | AddCommand; 

type Result<T> = 
    T extends RemoveCommand ? { status: string, a: number } :
    T extends AddCommand ? { status: string, b: number }:
    { status: string }

function send<T extends Command>(command: T): Result<T> {
  if (command instanceof RemoveCommand) {
    return { status: '', a: 0 } as Result<T>;
  } else if (command instanceof AddCommand) {
    return {
      status: '',
      b: 0,
    } as Result<T>
  }

  return {
    status: '',
  } as Result<T>
}

const r1: { a: number } = send(new RemoveCommand("foo"));
const r2: { b: number } = send(new AddCommand("bar"));
```

Comment: Thx a lot !
a and b are ok, because each command could have its own response.
Maybe there are some cases on how to force TS to make a nominal type check without change the public signature of the class?

Comment: @user3788219 TypeScript only does structural type checking, to the best of my knowledge.  Most of the types it has have no representation at runtime, and those that do exist at runtime often don't have a unique representation.